# What happens when a procedure executed by a JOB is not finished when is time for the JOB to execute it again?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I want to know what happens when a procedure is executed through a job and before it finishes is time for the job to call the next execution of the procedure. Here the job I created:

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
       (
          job        => x
         ,what       => 'BEGIN PKG_DISTRIBUIDOR_SCHEDULER.PRC_DISTRIBUYE_TRANSACCIONES(5000); END;'
         ,next_date  => to_date(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
         ,interval   => 'SYSDATE+30/86400'
         ,no_parse   => FALSE
       );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));   
       COMMIT;
   END;
```

As you can see, the job is executed each 30 seconds. So if my procedure (PRC_DISTRIBUYE_TRANSACCIONES) delays more than 30 seconds, what does the job do in this case?

Comment: Parameter **NEXT_DATE** is of type DATE and **SYSDATE** function returns a data of type DATE so you don't need to use **TO_DATE** function.    
You can get erronous dates using **to_date(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')** because Oracle first convert **SYSDATE** to text using database "NLS_DATE_FORMAT" setting which by default is "DD-MON-RR".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If you use the (old deprecated) Jobs, i.e. `DBMS_JOB`

The starting time for the next execution is determined when the current jobs is finished.
If you specify an interval as `SYSDATE+30/86400` then it **does not** mean: "The job runs every 30 seconds."

It means: "The next jobs starts 30 seconds after the previous job has been finished."

#### If you use the Scheduler Jobs, i.e. `DBMS_SCHEDULER`

Immediately after a job starts, the `repeat_interval` (e.g. `FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=30`) is evaluated to determine the next scheduled execution time of the job. While this might arrive while the job is still running, a new instance of the job does not start until the current one completes. See [About Setting the Repeat Interval](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN-GUID-CDAC9D52-61F2-484B-BF5E-874EDEAE2CD2)

So it means: If a jobs last longer than 30 seconds then the new job will start immediately after the previous job has been finished.

Comment: Great! Thanks man, great answer. Now, what if due the nature of my application I want the job to execute right after the previous executions has finished. I'm thinking in set the interval to one second but is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The statement to `DBMS_JOB`is probably not exact correct - I saw several job that **are running every 30 seconds**. If the job is finished withing this period, it works fine.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber perhaps the interval was `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MI')+30/86400`

Comment: No, just tested with INTERVAL `SYSDATE+5/86400`, job sleeps 3 seconds and the overall period is exact 5 seconds. Only when the job takes longer that the interval, you get out of sync.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, that's strange. Maybe the sleep runs in background.

Comment: If you want the job to run immediately after finishing I would prefer an infinite `LOOP` inside the procedure and start this procedure once.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens!
Only when anonymous PL/SQL block inside "**what**" parameter finish is the next date calculated according the **interval** parameter